# Obtener variable sin actulizar o refresacar la web de AJAX

Tags: php, ajax

¿Cómo saco la variable: (**numberbtc**) de AJAX sin refrescar la web y sin eliminar `$_POST` ni `<form>`?

Pues necesito que después de hacer `click` en `submit` me realice otras funciones:

Pagina **validate.php**

```
    <?php
$valor_Crypto       = $_POST['valor_Crypto'];
$Money              = $_POST['Money'];

if($valor_Crypto =='BTCTOUSD'){$cryptomoney = 'BITCOIN';    $moneda = 'BTC';
    $url="https://api.coinmarketcap.com/v1/ticker/".$cryptomoney."/";
    $data= file_get_contents('https://api.coinmarketcap.com/v1/ticker/'.$cryptomoney.'/',true);
    $json=json_decode($data);
    $price_usd = $json[0]->price_usd;
    $curl = curl_init($url);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_ENCODING ,"utf-8");
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    $data = curl_exec($curl);
    $json = json_decode($data);
    $price_usd = $json[0]->price_usd;
    $resultado1 = ($price_usd *5) / 100;
    $resultado2 = $price_usd + $resultado1;
    $resultado = $resultado2*$Money;
    echo "<tr><td><input type='text' placeholder='Result' class='field' readonly='readonly' value='".$resultado ."(USD)= ".$Money."(".$moneda.")'></td></tr>";
}
//Aqui va un IF con inserción en base datos enviada después de hacer click en Post
// IF(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    // mysql_query....
    // acciones varias
// }

?>
```

Pagina 2 **index.php**

```
        <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];?>" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="POST">
        <center>
                 <table class="calculadora" border="0">
                    <tr><td style="text-align:center"><h5>Calculator</h5></td>  </tr>
                    <tr><td style="text-align:center"><input type="number" placeholder="Money" name="Money" id="Money" onkeyup="busqueda();"/></td>  </tr>
                    <tr><td style="text-align:center">
                    <select name="valor_Crypto" id="valor_Crypto"  required/>
                                <option value=""><center>Coin Converter Calculator</center></option>
                                <option value="HTGTOUSD">HTG to USD</option>
                                <option value="USDTOHTG">USD to HTG</option>
                                <option value="USDTOBTC">USD to BTC</option>
                                <option value="USDTOETC">USD to ETC</option>
                                <option value="USDTOLTC">USD to LTC</option>
                                <option value="USDTODGC">USD to DGC</option>
                                <option value="BTCTOUSD">BTC to USD</option>
                                <option value="ETCTOUSD">ETC to USD</option>
                                <option value="LTCTOUSD">LTC to USD</option>
                                <option value="DGCTOUSD">DGC to USD</option>
                    </td></tr>
<!--me gustariq que input trabajara igual que div mostrando rsultado
NOTA: el div me funciona al 100% pero no 1) no es visible antes de ingresar datos y 2) no puedo insertar en mysql el ID optenido mediante un value. que el value seria lo de menos lo importante es que se visualise el campo text-->
<!--<tr><td><div id="numberbtc"></div></td></tr>-->
                    <tr><td style="text-align:center"><input type="submit" type="text" id="numberbtc" value="numberbtc"></div></td></tr>
                    <tr><td><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Enviar"></td></tr>

                </table>
        </center>
        </form>
       <script type="text/javascript" src="js/app.js"></script>
```

pagina de **app.js**

```
    function busqueda(){
    var valor_Crypto = document.getElementById("valor_Crypto").value;
    var Money = document.getElementById("Money").value;
    var parametros = {
        "valor_Crypto" : valor_Crypto,
        "Money" : Money
    };
    $.ajax({
        data: parametros,
        url:"js/valida.php",
        type: "POST",
        success: function(responce){
            $("#numberbtc").html(responce);

        }
    });
}
```

Comment: ¿Qué es lo que hace valida.js? Lo que yo haría sería devolver el valor que necesitas en el responce y luego capturarlo desde la vista, ¿No?

Comment: ¿"responce" llega a tener algún valor? Hazle un var_dump() para ver que tiene

Comment: Insisto, el problema son los nombre de variables, de lo que envias con lo que esperas en el backend, jamas entrara en el primer IF ya que nunca llegaran los campos `valor_Crypto` y `Money` ya que estas enviandole `variable1` y `variable1`. Creo que esto ya te lo respondi ayer.

Comment: Listo disculpa se me habia pasado ya la edite bro

Comment: Y mi problema bro no es el AJAX ni el validate ni siquiera si quito o elimino form o el  If mi problema es! ¿Cómo saco la variable: (numberbtc) de AJAX sin refrescar la web y sin eliminar $_POST ni <form> osea sin presionar el boton para que no se refresque amigo

Comment: Bueno ahora cambia un poco. Siendo asi, la pregunta, es que tu quieres obtener el resultado una vez que presiones el boton enviar, por que veo que llamas `busqueda()` cuando presionas alguna tecla en el input de `money`

Answer (score 0):

Una solucion para poder enviar los datos de forma asincrona y que la respuesta poder mostrarla en un elemento de la web, sin necesidad de refrescar la pagina seria de esta forma.

Teniendo en cuenta que usas jQuery

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];?>" id="formulario" method="POST">
<center>
         <table class="calculadora" border="0">
            <tr><td style="text-align:center"><h5>Calculator</h5></td>  </tr>
            <tr><td style="text-align:center"><input type="number" placeholder="Money" name="Money" id="Money" /></td>  </tr>
            <tr><td style="text-align:center">
                <select name="valor_Crypto" id="valor_Crypto"  required/>
                        <option value=""><center>Coin Converter Calculator</center></option>
                        <option value="HTGTOUSD">HTG to USD</option>
                        <option value="USDTOHTG">USD to HTG</option>
                        <option value="USDTOBTC">USD to BTC</option>
                        <option value="USDTOETC">USD to ETC</option>
                        <option value="USDTOLTC">USD to LTC</option>
                        <option value="USDTODGC">USD to DGC</option>
                        <option value="BTCTOUSD">BTC to USD</option>
                        <option value="ETCTOUSD">ETC to USD</option>
                        <option value="LTCTOUSD">LTC to USD</option>
                        <option value="DGCTOUSD">DGC to USD</option>
                </select>
            </td></tr>
            <tr><td style="text-align:center">
              <input type="text" name="numberbtc" id="numberbtc" value="">
             </td></tr>
            <tr><td><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Enviar"></td></tr>

        </table>
</center>
</form>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../../includes/js/app.js"></script>
```

En app.js

```
jQuery('document').ready(function(){

    jQuery("#formulario").on("submit", function(e) {
        e.preventDefault(); // Con esto evitamos que el formulario se envie.
        formulario = jQuery('#formulario');

        $.ajax({
            data: formulario.serialize(),
            url:"js/valida.php",
            type: "POST",
            success: function(response){
                $("#numberbtc").val(response);
            },
            error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown){
                console.log("Status: " + textStatus); alert("Error: " + errorThrown);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

De esta forma `jQuery("#formulario").on("submit", function(e)` detectará cuando presiones enviar formulario, y cuando esto pase `e.preventDefault();` evitara que se envíe. Con eso ya el resto se enviará de forma asincrona y el resultado se mostrara en el elemento `#numberbtc` o bien si existe un error será notificado en la consola.

Comment: Amigo tu respuesta es = a mi pregunta perdon cometi un ERROR es con Input no quiero nada con div por que el Input debe insertarse por medio del name

Comment: de hecho creo que debo explicarme mejor al realizar todo perfecto con un DIV pero no quiero eso en DIV por que el cuadro de texto no sale visible si no cuando insertan el monto entonces necesito que este en un input pre-existente.para que por medio de un value este se inserte en una tabla de mysql

Comment: acabo de modificar la respuesta, donde el valor retornado se da a un input. Ahora bien, este input es de tipo `text` si no lo quieres mostrar cambialo a tipo `hidden`

Comment: Ahora a tener en cuenta que lo que estas retornando es HTML, por ende saldrá eso en el input. Quizas no estoy entendiendo bien el problema.

Comment: esta bien mi edicio o es lo mismo que usted hizo?

Comment: Ya me perdi con lo que queires, ya que has modificado varias veces tu pregunta. Si quieres que la respuesta de PHP que consultas mediante AJAX de forma asincrona se muestre en el input que antes era un DIV, lo que publique servirá.
Pero ten en cuenta que estas retornando desde PHP etiquetas HTML, asi que en el input se mostrará lo retornado por PHP que es un HTML

Comment: el problema es que en div le pongo name y no inserta en mysql y por eso quiero un value dentro de un input

Comment: por eso tambien comente con la esperanza que quede claro me explico un poco mas supon algo imaginate que el formulario es mas grande lo usaras para enviarme un dinero Obvio faltan mas inputs como usuario, quien recibe, etc. en fin tu me enviaras 10 dolares

Comment: los cuales recibire yo pero la cantidad debe reflejarse según la escribas en el campo de crypto antes de enviar el formulario debes saber exactamente cuanto me llegara. en BTC y posteriormente precionas el boton submit enviando el formulario este inserta en mysql PEROOO!!! el campo valor no existe por que no hay un value o el DIV no inserta en ese campo exactamente el name= numberbtc